# eXistDB HTML Templating files outside of current app

Tags: exist-db

I’ve an eXistDB app set up with templating. Is it possible to make HTML Files outside of the app (in a different collection) use the same templating mechanisms to get the page header and styles and so on from my app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [eXist's HTML templating feature](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/templating) in any of your collections, but as the [set up](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/templating#D3.35) section of the documentation states, you will need to ensure the following modules responsible for handling the templating functionality are in the new collection:

- `controller.xql`
- `modules/view.xql`

For simplicity's sake, you could just copy these files from your original collection into the target collection, and they should work identically.

Comment: But I can't use the templating infrastructure from one collection (say `/db/apps/myapp`) with HTML Documents in another collection (`/db/apps/otherapp`)?

Comment: No, because without a controller.xql file in the (ancestor-or-self) collection hierarchy requested by the URL, the handlers for templating will not be called.